# Keeping the order of inserted data phpmyadmin

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I have some data I want to enter into my database however when I use the insert tab on phpmyadmin the data never keeps the order I inserted the data. How can I keep the order of the data being inserted. An example of the data is below.

track_id: 20, 20, 20

artist_id: 32, 26, 30

so the first track_id of 20 has an artist_id of 32 the second track_id had a artist_id of 26 and so on. When this is inserted into the db artist_id is sorted. I don't want that I want the data to stay in this order. Note none of these values are set as keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't manipulate how the server will insert the record on the database. It will write the row randomly on the table. So my advise in order to keep your desired order is to add another column that will identify the sort. eg.

```
track_id:  20, 20, 20
artist_id: 32, 26, 30
position:   1,  2,  3
```

and on your query, order the records by the column that holds the position during projection of data.

```
SELECT  track_id, artist_id
FROM    tableName
-- WHERE  track_id = 20
ORDER   BY position ASC
```

Comment: Thanks I thought this could have been done in another way. But this will do just fine.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT  track_id, artist_id FROM tableName WHERE  track_id = 20 ORDER BY position ASC